# Pandas groupby transform covariance

Tags: pandas

My DataFrame:

```
A = pd.DataFrame({'group':['A','A','A','A','B','B','B'],
              'value1':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
              'value2':[8,5,4,3,7,8,8]})
```

I'd like to have a new column, covariance, that show the covariance between [value1,value2] on the group-level, for each observation.

Therefore I tried:

```
A['covariance'] = A.groupby('group')[['value1','value2']].transform(lambda x: x['value1'].cov(x['value2']),axis=1)
```

But this results in error:

```
TypeError: Transform function invalid for data types
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need to specify the columns a bit differently:

```
>>> A.groupby('group')['value1'].transform(lambda x: x.cov(A['value2']))
0   -2.666667
1   -2.666667
2   -2.666667
3   -2.666667
4    0.500000
5    0.500000
6    0.500000
```

This works like:

```
>>> for _, frame in A.groupby('group'):
...     print(frame['value1'].cov(frame['value2']))
... 
-2.6666666666666665
0.5
```

Side note - I find this syntax a bit confusing because `A.groupby('group')` is an iterator over tuples of (`'group', 'df'`).    But I think this stems from the fact that

> The transform function must: Operate column-by-column on the group
>   chunk. The transform is applied to the first group chunk using
>   chunk.apply. [(source)](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#groupby-transform)

And as a disclosure, generally, throwing a `lambda` inside the call may (*may*, but not always) make things slower by putting computation in the Python space (rather than Cython).

Comment: This is pretty neat. What exactly is going on here? `A['value2']` is entire original Series, so do we get by because `x` gets reindexed and filled with `NaN` and in this case it works because the `NaN` wont change the covaraince, so we effectively just calculate it within group?

Comment: Yeah, I would venture to call it a bit unintuitive @ALollz - it doesn't seem to follow the usual convention of how to call stuff on groupby objects.

Comment: At first glance, I would've thought `A.groupby('group').transform(lambda df: df['value1'].cov(A['value2']))` would be the solution, because each "group" in `A.groupby('group')` is a DataFrame with the 3 original columns.

Comment: Yeah, I think with transform `lambda` is needed, since it really can't act across columns. Generally, I'm used to something like: `my_cov = lambda gp: gp.cov(A.loc[gp.index, 'value2'])` so it specifically only acts within group. But for the cov `NaN` handling it seems to work without the subsetting.